# MySQL logs per day

Tags: mysql, logging

With XAMPP, I configure in apache dynamic access and error logs with rotatelogs.exe with the following line in the httpd.conf:

```
ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -l C:/xampp/apache/logs/error-%Y-%m-%d.log 86400"
```

And now I have log files per day like this:

```
error-2017-03-08.log
error-2017-03-07.log
error-2017-03-06.log
```

I want to do the same with MySQL slow query log, general log and error log

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/log-file-maintenance.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rotating mysql slow query log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601658/rotating-mysql-slow-query-log)